# C++ Delete a running application with itself

Tags: c++

I made an application in c++ and now it's really important for me to make a function and when i call it the application closes and delete it's executable file (for security reasons)

How such a thing can be done , with `CreateRemoteThread` or something else ? any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to handle the problems you want to avoid. What if the user simply makes a copy of the executable before running it ? What are you trying to avoid ?

Comment: Have you considered permissions?  I.e. perms on executable != perms of user running executable.

Comment: C++ doesn't have any facilities to do this. This can only be done with the help of the target platform (which you should specify). And don't fool yourself into believing this is any more secure. An attacker can simply read an application's process memory before you get a chance to delete the binary image.

Comment: @IInspectable if you make that an answer you've got at least my upvote.

Comment: My application is a server, and it is always in my own server, i want this feature for when someone (in any way) steal the application so i can delete the app by sending a tcp packet to the app ( deleting the app file is the least i want to do, if i dont find any way for it i will format the whole stealer's hard disk ;) )

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to delete itself while running. BUT if your application have the permission to write to the disk, you can create a shell (on linux) or batch (on windows) to delete all the files (a batch file can also delete itself). then just before closing the app you can call the batch with a system call. and on the batch you can wait for i.e. 3 secs before deletion (wait for the app to close)

Comment: That seems like a silly way to solve the problem. They would just have to keep a second copy...

Comment: @MatsPetersson You know a better way ?

Comment: No, I'm not sure of a better way, but my point is that it's very easy to overcome your mechanism by keeping a second copy (and using a batch file, to copy a new file and start it. Whenever it stops, create a new copy [if it doesn't exist already] and run in an infinite loop). I'd probably look at node-locking, or some other such thing. Also, make sure your security is good. I'm also not sure how you'd detect that someone has stolen the executable in the first place.

Comment: @Shahriyar Frankly, this is rather stupid and almost certainly the wrong solution to a *bad* question. The simple fact is that there's *no way* to programatically prevent someone with physical access to the machine from making a copy of your application. If your security model depends on being able to delete your app, then your security model is **broken**. You ask if Mats knows a better way. That's the wrong question. The question you should be asking is "how do I design a sensible security model?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the executable is running, you can't delete it.

You could create a wrapper executable (or for example a batch file) that starts the other executable, and when it's finished deletes the executable file.

Comment: I mean first close the app and then with a thread that i made in other processes, delete the app file

Comment: So, if you already have to have two processes [and you are not planning to hijack some existing process - which is not something I would recommend as a solution, because antivirus software for example may reject such a solution], then why not just let the other process delete the file.